# Thread 1: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type __ found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for __ may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

When ever I try to run my program, I get a fatal error that 'A View.environmentObject(_:) for __ may be missing as an ancestor of this view.', and I don't really understand the error.

Here's my code:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var storage = Variables()
    var body: some View {
        AddToScore()
        VStack {
            Button("remove points") {
                storage.score -= 1
            }
            Text("text text etxt dfahjadfbadful")
        }.environmentObject(storage)
    }
}

struct AddToScore: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var storage: Variables
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Point generator")
                .font(.title)
            HStack {
                Button("Get points!") {
                    storage.score += 1
                }
                Text("\(storage.score)")
            }
        }
    }
}

class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is that `.environmentObject(storage)` is not in range of AddToScore(). They are both 'on the same level'. `.environmentObject(storage)` needs to be on the level above. Like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var storage = Variables()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            AddToScore() // AddToScore() needs to be a level below .environmentObject(storage).
            Button("remove points") {
                storage.score -= 1
            }
            Text("text text etxt dfahjadfbadful")
        }.environmentObject(storage)
    }
}

struct AddToScore: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var storage: Variables
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Point generator")
                .font(.title)
            HStack {
                Button("Get points!") {
                    storage.score += 1
                }
                Text("\(storage.score)")
            }
        }
    }
}

class Variables: ObservableObject {
    @Published var score = 0
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

You could also add `.environmentObject(storage)` directly on `AddToScore()` (as shown on the comment by Umer Khan).

```swift
AddToScore().environmentObject(storage)
```

Comment: The modifier must be with a View which requires environment object

AddToScore().environmentObject(storage)